# Does the space between field lines inside the conductor increase with distance and eventually disappear?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, conductors, vector-fields

In practical scenarios where resistance is present, what happens to the electric field lines within a conductor? Practically, we say there is no flow of current in a high resistance conductor with a small potential difference(For example, a 10m long carbon rod with 1mm diameter). Is it because there is no electric field when we go further in the conductor. Or is it because the electric force is little to exceed resistance? And what happens to the electric field lines? Do they emerge out of the conductor (Is that the reason for electrons' inability to travel to the other terminal.)

Comment: 'Practically, we say there is no flow of current in a high resistance conductor with a small potential difference.' Who says this? It violates Ohm's law.

Comment: @my2cts That is what I was saying. Ohms law is theoritical. I am not denying the fact that voltage difference and current are proportional to each other.

Comment: @my2cts I edited the question so you can better understand.

Comment: The electric field is constant inside a wire due to surface charges.

Comment: @jensenpaull That's under static electric states, right? Are there surface charges in a conductor at dynamic electric state?